# How do I make a query equalto with a long value?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I tried to make a query from real time database using equalTo().

```
database.getReference(verifiedProductsDb.dbPartVerifiedProducts).order By Child(verifiedProductsDb.barcode).equalTo(b.toLong()).get().addOnCompleteListener {
```

but android studio gives out:

```
None of the following functions can be called with the argument supplied.
equalTo(Boolean) defined in com.google.firebase.database.Query
equalTo(Double) defined in com.google.firebase.database.Query
equal To(String?) defined in com.google.firebase.database.Query
```

Despite the fact that using setValue, long values are written to the same database quite successfully and without problems.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Realtime Database API on Android only has support for `Double` number types. The underlying wire protocol and database will interpret the long numbers correctly though, so you should be able to just do:

```
database.getReference("VerifiedProducts")
  .orderByChild("barcode")
  .equalTo(b.toLong().toDouble()) // 
  .get().addOnCompleteListener {
    ...
```